# how to get actual animation play position without using animator in untity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

```
 anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
 float length = anim.clip.length;
 Debug.Log(length);
```

will show me following result:

```
 45
```

If this position will be achieved, animation should start at begining again. Any ideas, how to achieve this using C# Scripting? I am not using any animator, just animation in ChildObject.
This will not work, of course, 'cause its always true:

```
if(length==45)
anim.Restart();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just looks like your looking to trigger a restart at the end of the animation.  So insert an AnimationEvent at the end of the animation.  Look at Unity's simple Scripting API example.  Ignore the fact that they are using an Animator, they just use it to get the clip.  Obviously, you will already have your clip.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationEvent.html

Here is the modified Unity script from the link above.

```
public void Start()
{
    // existing components on the GameObject
    AnimationClip clip;

    // new event created
    AnimationEvent evt;
    evt = new AnimationEvent();

    // put some parameters on the AnimationEvent
    //  - call the function called PrintEvent()
    //  - the animation on this object lasts 2 seconds
    //    and the new animation created here is
    //    set up to happen 1.3s into the animation
    evt.intParameter = 12345;
    evt.time = 1.3f;
    evt.functionName = "PrintEvent";

    clip.AddEvent(evt);
}

// the function to be called as an event
public void PrintEvent(int i)
{
    print("PrintEvent: " + i + " called at: " + Time.time);
}
```

Comment: Great. Gave u reputation points for ur efforts. I'm not using AnimationClip, i'm just using Animation. What's difference?

Comment: Thanks.  Just looked it up.  Never used it before - apparently `Animation` is a Legacy way of performing animations.  Unity switched over to an `AnimationClip`/`Animator` coupling sometime ago.  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationScripting.html If you can, try and switch over to using `AnimationClip`.  It's pretty easy ESPECIALLY if you're using 1 animation.  If you're blending more than one, it looks like it'll be more difficult.  But again, I've never used it before.